# C# Why does Except and Where Enumerable Give This Weird Result?

Tags: c#, enumerator, ienumerator

I have been debugging this production bug for sometime and I'm desperate for help and also it's interesting to me.

I have simplified the code logic and added some print-out for debugging:

```
int[] a = { 2,2,2 };
var b = a.Where(x => x==2);

for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    var c = b.Where(x => x==i);

    Console.WriteLine("iter {0} before - B Count: {1}, C Count: {2}", i, b.Count(), c.Count());

    if (c.Count() != b.Count())
        b = b.Except(c);

    Console.WriteLine("iter {0} after - B Count: {1}, C Count: {2}", i, b.Count(), c.Count());
}

Console.WriteLine("After Loop: B Count: {0}", b.Count());
```

Interestingly (Weirdly), the output is:

```
iter 0 before - B Count: 3, C Count: 0
iter 0 after - B Count: 1, C Count: 0
iter 1 before - B Count: 1, C Count: 0
iter 1 after - B Count: 1, C Count: 0
iter 2 before - B Count: 0, C Count: 0
iter 2 after - B Count: 0, C Count: 0
After Loop: B Count: 1
```

### Question 1:

Why `b.Count() == 0` at "iter 2 before". The only thing happens between "iter 1 after and iter 2 before" is

```
var c = b.Where(x => x==i);
```

Why does this code change b at all?

### Question 2:

Why does `b.Count()` become back to 1 after the loop is finished?

I really appreciate everyone's help to guide me through this problem, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Due to linq's lazy evaluation, each of the `Where` and `Except` calls is executed every time you make a call to `Count()`. What's important to note here is that the value of `i` is not remembered, instead it takes the current value of `i` for all the previous `Where` calls.

> Why b.Count() == 0 at "iter 2 before"

At this point, `i` has already been incremented to `2`. When you call count, the entire linq query is evaluated using this value, meaning that the previously added 'Except` call will already remove everything!

> Why does b.Count() become back to 1 after the loop is finished?

The loop ends when `i` equals 3. Now when you evaluate the entire linq query, none of the `.Where(x => x==i)` calls will return anything, which in turn means that none of the `Except` calls will remove anything (other than the duplicates).

Comment: Nice catch. A workaround would be to force execution right away.. `ToList().AsEnumerable()`.

Comment: @Rouby a simpler one is just to change the scope of the captured variable (see my answer for an example)

Answer (score 3):

For **1**: "Why does this code change b at all?"

It doesn't. Add (at the start of the loop, before `c`):

```
Console.WriteLine("iter {0} before anything - B Count: {1}", i, b.Count());
```

`b` is unchanged.

For **2**: that's because of the captured `i`. Change to:

```
for(int tmp = 0 ; tmp < 3 ; tmp++) {
      int i = tmp;
    // ...
}
```

and try again. Now the `i` is scoped *inside* the loop, and is captured accordingly (the iterator variable in a `for` loop is scoped *outside* the loop, for complicated reasons; in a `foreach` loop, whether the iterator variable is scoped inside or outside the loop depends on the version of C# you are using)

Answer (score 1):

`Except` acts like its SQL counterpart in that it eliminates duplicates. Because of this, it behaves as if it called `Distinct` on your list.

So when you first execute `Except`

```
if (c.Count() != b.Count()) // c.Count() == 0, b.Count() == 3
    b = b.Except(c);
```

You only get the unique elements of `b`, of which there is only one.

Answer (score 0):

[`Enumerable.Except`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb300779%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) produces the set difference of two sequences by using the default equality comparer to compare values. A set does not contain duplicates.

That's why the sequence only contain one 2 after `Except`.

```
int[] onlyOneTwo = new[]{ 2,2,2 }.Except(Enumerable.Empty<int>()).ToArray();
```

So the empty sequence does not remove anything but `Except` that [uses a set](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,e289e6c98881b2b8,references).